# Puppeter find element in current page OR iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, iframe, puppeteer

I have some elements in my page which are sometimes in iFrame, sometimes don't.
They have the same id to identify them in both cases.

What is the best and quickly way to find them in page or iFrame ?

I currently use this code which works when elements are in the iFrame, but which doesn't work if the element are simply in the page.
I thought the mainFrame would be the "currentPage" outside the iFrame, but it seems the code search only in iFrames, not outside.

```
async function recursiveFindInFrames(inputFrame, selector) {
  const frames = inputFrame.childFrames();
  const results = await Promise.all(
    frames.map(async frame => {
      const el = await frame.$(selector);
      if (el) return el;
      if (frame.childFrames().length > 0) {
        return await recursiveFindInFrames(frame, selector);
      }
      return null;
    })
  );
  return results.find(Boolean);
}

async function findInFrames(page, selector) {
  const result = await recursiveFindInFrames(page.mainFrame(), selector);
  if (!result) {
    console.log('The selector ',selector,' could not be found in any child frames.')
  }
  return result;
}
...
//Element that could be in an iFrame, or not
const element = await findInFrames(page2, 'input[name="myField"]');
await element.click();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely easier to find any element when it's in the same page, and you don't need a special function to do that.

This is enough if you know the element's id: `$('#element_id')` (you can also use a variable if the element's id is not hardcoded).

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just add a `page.evaluate` with a `querySelector`?

```
async function findInFrames(page, selector) {
  const framesResult = await recursiveFindInFrames(page.mainFrame(), selector);
  if (!framesResult) {
    console.log('The selector ',selector,' could not be found in any child frames.')
  }
  const pageResult = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector(selector))
  return framesResult || pageResult || null; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check the main page in addition to nested child frames, you can check the `inputFrame` initially before iterating through child frames. It could look something like this:

```
async function recursiveFindInFrames(inputFrame, selector) {
  var el = await inputFrame.$(selector);
  if (el) {
     return el;
  }
  const childFrames = inputFrame.childFrames();
  for (let i = 0; i < childFrames.length; i++) {
    el = await recursiveFindInFrames(childFrames[i], selector);
    if (el) {
      return el;
    }
  }
  return null;
}

async function findInFrames(page, selector) {
  const result = await recursiveFindInFrames(page.mainFrame(), selector);
  if (!result) {
    console.log('The selector, ' + selector + ', could not be found in any child frames.')
  }
  return result;
}
...
//Element that could be in an iFrame, or not
const element = await findInFrames(page2, 'input[name="myField"]');
if (element) {
  await element.click();
}
...
```

Note that this method sequentially searches, awaiting for the results from each frame. If you want to search child frames in parallel, you can do something like this:

```
async function recursiveFindInFrames(inputFrame, selector) {
  var el = await inputFrame.$(selector);
  if (el) {
     return el;
  }
  const childFrames = inputFrame.childFrames();
  const elementPromises = childFrames.map(frame => recursiveFindInFrames(frame, selector));
  for (let i = 0; i < elementPromises.length; i++) {
    el = await elementPromises[i];
    if (el) {
      return  el;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

That said, I think the potential improvement would be pretty small.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `frames` method instead of `childFrames`.
So this code

```
  const frames = inputFrame.childFrames();
```

Should be written like this:

```
   const frames = inputFrame.frames();
```

The frames method returns the MainFrame as well in an array. So, the function will also search on the mainFrame.